# PS Script to get data from excel then remove permissions on shared folder

Tags: excel, powershell

Im creating a simple script to remove user's permission on a shared drive folder. I have the usernames and shared drive folders in an excel file. Only 2 columns, 1 for path and the other one is the usernames.

Here's what I've done with the script

```
$file = "C:\share\LanguagePack\testing.xlsx"
$SheetName = "Sheet1"
$objExcel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$objExcel.Visible = $false
$WorkBook = $objExcel.Workbooks.Open($file)
$WorkSheet = $WorkBook.Sheets.Item($SheetName)
$WorkSheetRange = $WorkSheet.UsedRange
$RowCount = $WorkSheetRange.Rows.Count
$ColumnCount = $WorkSheetRange.Columns.Count


for ($num2=1, $num2 -lt $RowCount, $num2++) {

    $output = $WorkSheet.cells.Item($num2, 1).text
    $output1 = $WorkSheet.cells.Item($num2, 2).text

    icacls $output /remove:g $output1 /t

}
```

but im getting

Could not compare "1" to "3 3". Error: "Cannot convert the "System.Object[]" 
value of type "System.Object[]" to type "System.Int32"."
At C:\share\LanguagePack\Untitled1.ps1:26 char:6
+ for ($num2=1, $num2 -lt $RowCount, $num2++) {
+      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ComparisonFailure

Any ideas or tips? Thanks

Comment: Use semicolons `;` in the `for` loop, not commas.

Comment: yep, didnt realize that. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$file = "C:\share\LanguagePack\testing.xlsx"
$SheetName = "Sheet1"
$objExcel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$objExcel.Visible = $false
$WorkBook = $objExcel.Workbooks.Open($file)
$WorkSheet = $WorkBook.Sheets.Item($SheetName)
$WorkSheetRange = $WorkSheet.UsedRange
$RowCount = $WorkSheetRange.Rows.Count
$ColumnCount = $WorkSheetRange.Columns.Count

for($row=1; $row -le $RowCount; $row++) {

    $output = $WorkSheet.cells.Item($row, 1).text
    $output1 = $WorkSheet.cells.Item($row, 2).text

    icacls $output /remove:g $output1 /t
}
```

Comment: it only processed the last row data not all the data in the excel :(

Comment: @Gang12: Realized my mistake... Edited the code now. This should work.

Answer (score 0):

As I have already commented, the mistake you have made is using commas `,` in the `foreach` loop instead of semicolons `;`

The commas make Powershell think it is an array of some sort, hence the error

```
"Cannot convert the "System.Object[]" value of type "System.Object[]" to type "System.Int32""
```

This should work:

```
for ($num2=1; $num2 -lt $RowCount; $num2++) {

    $output = $WorkSheet.cells.Item($num2, 1).text
    $output1 = $WorkSheet.cells.Item($num2, 2).text

    icacls $output /remove:g $output1 /t
}
```